# Looking for an Open Source Project Management system supporting notifications

Tags: software-recommendation, open-source, project-management

I am looking for an Open Source Project Management system supporting notifications.

Here's my requirement:

We need an database based system which can track tasks and their due dates.
There should be an option to specify start date, due date and end date.
As soon as date is due, application should trigger an email alert.
Any pointers on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so software recommendations are off-topic here as well. However, on http://http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're specialised in software recommendations, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various options, but I would recommend you to go with [**Redmine**](http://www.redmine.org/).

> Redmine is a flexible project management web application. Written
>   using the Ruby on Rails framework, it is cross-platform and
>   cross-database.
>
> Redmine is open source and released under the terms of the GNU General
>   Public License v2 (GPL).

It has the features you request and is very scalable, it can easily cope with large organisations and multiple projects, but is largely seamless for small teams. Some of the features that might interest you:

- Gantt chart and calendar
- Feeds & email notifications
- Time tracking
- Multiple databases support